# Value Error: invalid literalfor int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: python, string, file, input, casting

Ok guys, I am using python to try to complete a task.  In short, I need to read in a number from a text file that can be thousands of digits long.  I'm getting this error as I try to take the digits from the string and cast them to integers so I can do some math with them.

```
of = open("input.txt","r")
counter = 0
big=0
of.seek(0,0)

while True:    
    temp = of.read(5)
    if temp=="":
        break
    else:    
        a=int(temp[0])
        b=int(temp[1])
        c=int(temp[2])
        d=int(temp[3])
        e=int(temp[4])
        if a*b*c*d*e>big:
            big = a*b*c*d*e
        counter+=1
        of.seek(counter,0)

print big
of.close()
```

I'm really stuck on this one so any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT==============================================================

After tinkering around a bit I finally got the code to run correctly.  Here's what I ended with:

```
x = int(open("input.txt","r").read())
y = str(x)
big = 0
for i in range(0,len(y)-5):
    a = int(y[i])
    b = int(y[i+1])
    c = int(y[i+2])
    d = int(y[i+3])
    e = int(y[i+4])
    if a*b*c*d*e>big:
        big = a*b*c*d*e
print big
```

thanks for the help

Comment: The indent of your code seems incorrect. My suggestion is to add "try" "except" in this code block and print the input string to int() which caused the exception.

Comment: Well, what exactly do you want to happen when you encounter a space in the line that you read in? Explain more about what your file actually contains and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Basically there will be only one number -- a very long integer -- read in through the input file.  I need to take in the numbers, digits at a time at multiply them.  I am just having problems with the input.  There should be no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Python supports long integers so if the file is just one big integer you can read it like this:

```
bignum=int(open("input.txt","r").read())
```

Comment: this gives me almost the same error:
Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'integerFrom.txt'
where the 'integerFrom.txt' is the number that's read from the input file.

Comment: Are there any non-numeric characters in the file? You can check by running open('integerFrom.txt','r').read().isdigit()

Comment: nope.  this is designed for only files with one long integer.  I included an edit above that included the correct code; however, it may not be the optimal way in which it should be done.  Thanks for the interest :)

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong; `if-else` should be nested inside the `while` loop.